# Xcode 9 No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I went to build my app and I got this error:

> No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6
>   armv7).

I dont understand what I am doing wrong, here are my architectures

[image]

Comment: If you want to build for arm64 (and I imagine you do), add it to the list of valid architectures.

Comment: Now I get a new error `Invalid bitcode signature`

Comment: Google "Invalid bitcode signature" says, 'About 1,970 results'.

Comment: Yea, Im doing that, its an issue with a framework.

Comment: try to put in "Valid Architectures"  "arm64,armv7,armv7s"

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Armv6 is outdated, it hasn't been implemented since iOS 4.3

The standard recommended valid architectures are arm64, armv7 and armv7s. Here are a couple of apple technical documents that offer more detail.

[Technical Q&A QA1910](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1910/_index.html)

[iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)